# What file extensions are blocked by default in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Some files are not served off of IIS because they are typically part of the building blocks of the website itself. For ASP.NET these are files like *.cs, *.dll, *.config, *.cshtml, etc.

You can find a list of them tied up in the IIS management setting "Filter requests" here:

[image: Filter requests]

But if you need to programmatically access this list, it seems tough to find. Is there a good list of these default extensions?

BTW, the IIS website has info on how to enable / disable these globally here:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the list I build out of the IIS UI since I couldn't find it anywhere. Hope you find it helpful.

disallowed extensions

```
.asax
.ascx
.master
.skin
.browser
.sitemap
.config
.cs
.csproj
.vb
.vbproj
.webinfo
.licx
.resx
.resources
.mdb
.vjsproj
.java
.jsl
.ldb
.dsdgm
.ssdgm
.lsad
.ssmap
.cd
.dsprototype
.lsaprototype
.sdm
.sdmDocument
.mdf
.ldf
.ad
.dd
.ldd
.sd
.adprototype
.lddprototype
.exclude
.refresh
.compiled
.msgx
.vsdisco
.rules
```

Answer (score 7):

If I'm not mistaken, you'll find them in the *root* `web.config` of the machine:

> %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\framework_version\CONFIG

Which is also where you'll find the `machine.config` file.

e.g.

```
<add path="*.ascx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" validate="True" />
```

REF:

- Technet: [working with config files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754617%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- KB: [Use ASP.NET to Protect File Types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815152)

As to how you'd *programmatically* get to it - I haven't tried. The **IIS_USRS** built-in group  has access to it and [this doc](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis) expands on it.

Hth...

Comment: Nice. Funny, I looked there. But for some reason search the file didn't turn it up. I was looking for a fileExtension section (which the IIS doc I referenced talks about). Good to know. I suspect you can access this using `ConfigurationManager` but I haven't tried that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on localhost you can alter the applicationHost.config file, a systems file that you can edit in VS and go to the requestFiltering section, change and save.