# Saving ASP.NET MVC settings in xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to save settings for our ASP.NET MVC 4 project in an xml file. In the MVC-part of the solution I made the following path: `/Settings/Data/sitesettings.xml`.

This xml file has some info about the site and also has the api keys and smtp and ftp info stored. When I run the application on localhost I can access and change the file using

```
 private static string settingsXmlFile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(".\\Settings\\Data\\sitesettings.xml");
```

When I deploy the website, it just keeps loading, when I navigate to /Settings/Data/sitesettings.xml I can see the contents of the xml file which is REALLY bad.

So there are a few downsides and I would like to know what the best option would be for saving settings in an xml file. I'd like a (static) class from which I can access and write to the file, and I certainly would like the file to not be publicly available via the link...

How do I fix the issue (site keeps loading when deployed) and how can I make it more secure? Or should I use another way of saving settings?

Answer (score 0):

[These extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828476/what-file-extensions-are-blocked-by-default-in-iis) are denied by default by IIS, so users can't request them over HTTP. I'd suggest using `.config`. You can also [use the `Web.config`'s `AppSettings` section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/610xe886(v=vs.100).aspx) to store configuration values.

> When I deploy the website, it just keeps loading

That's a different question.

Comment: I'll take a look at saving in a config files, seems logical. Is it easy to read/ write, could I use the xml read write but just name it .config? Als I thought for settings in AppSettings the side has to be restarted after changes?