# File or directory not found although it exists and the path is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a problem - I cannot find my file when I open it using http://localhost:49652/.well-known/acme-challenge/FfI7Xeq7_QH5R5pCd3LhAkU4k3nOqBz9mNbvJ9EwMoQ although it exists and the path is correct.

I use ASP.NET C#, OS: Windows Server 2012 And IIS 8.0.

[image: Image Path My Website]

And error:

[image: Image Error]

Help me... Please!

Comment: Please add code instead of images.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I just want to access the file, absolutely no code. I think due to Web.Config blocked access. So I'll up the Web.config

Comment: Yes! I put a file there called bob.txt and can access it.

Comment: My Web.config: http://codepad.org/0xYrEsse

Comment: This image folder and file in acme-changlenge: https://imgur.com/a/NPNUByR only file count.txt can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to forward you to an other question: [What file extensions are blocked by default in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828476/what-file-extensions-are-blocked-by-default-in-iis)

The issue is that IIS has a configuration, how to handle requested files.
Depending on the extension, there have to be done different actions: While resources like .txt or .jpg files are just sent into the network as they are stored on the disk, other files like .aspx or .asmx have to be parsed, executed in dotnet and then the output have to be sent etc.
Other extensions like .dll or .exe are blocked by default, I think.

The problem is, that your files do not have any extension, so for this directory you have to configure that IIS should pass through all of the files.

Found another usefull link to microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/fileextensions/

Comment: Thanks you. How to Add Allowed File Name **No Extensitions** ? I can not find document for it

Comment: In IIS-Manager navigate to the directory that contains the files. In the main area there is a lik to "MIME-Type" in IIS-section. When I open it then I see a list of all the file extensions and their mime-type for direct download. There I added a new one with extension "." (only the dot without anything behind) and mime-type "text/plain". Now a file with no extension is downloaded as plain text from this (and only from this) directory.